Why would a queue fail to delete?
Running ActiveMQ Classic 6.0.1 embedded in a Spring Boot app. The app creates queues dynamically and publishes messages to them (via Spring's JmsTemplate); a companion app reads messages from those queues.
Using JConsole and JMS Toolbox I have observed that the queues never go away even hours or days after the last message has been dequeued and processed successfully. setSchedulePeriodForDestinationPurge has been set to a reasonable positive value for the embedded broker, and gcInactiveDestinations is set to true in the default PolicyMap. I've enabled broker logging to observe when destinations are removed.
In an effort to clean up the obsolete queues after the app is finished with them, I have tried all the documented ways (I could find) to explicitly delete a queue:

Region.removeDestination(context, queue, 5000)
ActiveMQConnection.destroyDestination(queue)
BrokerService.getAdminView().removeQueue(queueName)

None of these throw an exception, but neither do they actually delete the queue.
The only way to get the dynamically-created queues to go away is to restart the app (and its embedded broker). Nope, that doesn't work, either.
Why would the queues refuse to delete and yet not throw any exceptions? How can I actually clean up the (no longer used) queues?
